# jQuery how to use td background color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$("td").each(function () {
   if($(this).css("background-Color")=="red") {
      $(this).text()=="dd";
   }
   else if($(this).css("background-Color")=="blue") {
      $(this).text("aa");
   }
});
```

how the code should be written in the right way?

Comment: It returns raw format, not color name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the red color like this:

```
 if($(this).css("background-Color")=="rgb(255, 0, 0)"){
     ....
 }
```

and blue:

```
 if($(this).css("background-Color")=="rgb(0, 0, 255)"){
     ....
 }
```